# We don't talk anymore

Tags: word-choice, phrases, idioms, lyrics

I know its been over a year since this track of Charlie Puth came out but the lyrics of this [song](https://genius.com/Charlie-puth-we-dont-talk-anymore-lyrics) set me thinking on the use of the phrase

**We don't ___ anymore**

To me, the only word that sits perfectly in context is '*talk*'. The speaker intends to tell that *They* don't talk with each other.

While words like '*smile*' doesn't do the same trick. That would imply both would never smile at all, not just restricting its domain to themselves. This would've worked better: '*we don't smile at each other*'.

Am I getting it wrong? Or is he just using the poetic license in these lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute more or less any verb you like and it would still have the same meaning.

It's inferred that he's talking about himself and the other person doing the activity, but it's just as correct to use that sentence for them doing the activity independently.

Examples: We don't talk anymore, we don't sail anymore and we don't play football anymore etc.